# Service to query call log using LoaderManager or straightforward getContentResolver().query?

Tags: android, performance, android-service, android-loadermanager, android-background

I have a service that is already running on the background and I want to use it to read the call log (and many other tasks)
Some articles online suggest that I do this task using a loadermanager so it won't affect the performance of my activity. I can also do it using getApplicationContext.getContentResolver().query() though.
However, since a service is already running on the background, do I need to create more background tasks or can I just run everything from inside the service?
Thanks in advance :)